# SonarQube ignores .mailmap during SCM blame

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using:

- SonarQube Server 5.1.1
- Sonar Ant Tasks 2.3

I have a couple of authors in a Git repository that I want to change the name that is displayed in Sonar.

In the log I can see this:

```
Trying to guess scm provider from project layout...
Found SCM type: git 
... 
Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=5ms"
```

In the SonarQube documentation site, they recommended to have the .mailmap file to map the authors, however it doesn't seem to work:
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SCM+Activity+Plugin

I confirmed that the .mailmap is correct since I can see the modified author in the log, by running (for instance):

`git shortlog -sne`

`git log --use-mailmap`

What might be the problem?

Comment: Version of SonarQube? Version of the SCM Activity Plugin?

Comment: Added that info to the question. Regarding the SCM Activity plugin, I don't know which version it uses. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SonarQube 5.1.1 you are for sure not using the SCM Activity plugin that was used for 4.5.x and earlier. Instead it is using a standalone SonarQube Git plugin that internally rely on a pure Java implementation (JGit). Unfortunately JGit doesn't support mailmap files. This is a known issue http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARSCGIT-4.

But in SQ 5.x this is less an issue since you can explicitly associate one or more SCM account to a single SQ account. So even if a single user has several SCM account you can have the issues properly assigned to him. Remaining issue is when you are using commercial developer cockpit plugin since aggregation by developer doesn't take into account (yet) this configuration. This should be fixed in 5.2.

Comment: and how can I associate the SCM account(s) to the SQ account?

Comment: Administration -> Security -> Users -> Edit one user and you'll see a text field "SCM Accounts"

Comment: then, if indeed the SonarQube Git plugin doesn't support the .mailmap file, the documentation should mention this, instead of suggesting to use the .mailmap when then it's not used at all by Sonar.

Comment: BTW, the "SCM Accounts" functionality doesn't solve this problem completely - the issues are now correctly assigned to the SonarQube user but the blame info is still referring the original Git author email.